# Div invade otro div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos div que tienen que estar en **fixed** para que siempre se queden en el tope de la pagina, pero el div de arriba está comiéndose poco espacio del div que tiene los menús.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/5MrEX

Comment: Pon el código aquí, en lugar de un enlace. Puedes añadir snippets de código en la pregunta

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que no has especificado las propiedades que alinean el elemento, entonces toma por defecto el `top: 0` y `left: 0`, y como ambos tienen el `position: fixed` quedan solapandose, si quieres que tu menú este alejado debes darle un valor a tu `top`, `top: 13px` por ejemplo y tu menú se desplazara la cantidad en px que ayas especificados.

Comment: ¡Gracias por sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es darle un `top` al header que equivalga al `height` de la barra superior, así lograrás que no lo tape.

```
.inheader {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 11%;
    width: 75%;
    top: 13px;
}
```